# $.post returns object when aiming for simple php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I guess I'm just having difficulty with $.post... I've used it successfully in the past, but I have to be forgetting something important. All I want is a "hello world", but I'm getting a complicated object. I am befuddled.

**var_test.php**

```
<?php
    PRINT "hi";
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head>
    var thing = $.post( "var_test.php");
    console.log(thing);
</head><body></body></html>
```

**console output**

```
Object { readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: .ajax/v.getResponseHeader(), getAllResponseHeaders: .ajax/v.getAllResponseHeaders(), setRequestHeader: .ajax/v.setRequestHeader(), overrideMimeType: .ajax/v.overrideMimeType(), statusCode: .ajax/v.statusCode(), abort: .ajax/v.abort(), state: .Deferred/d.state(), always: .Deferred/d.always(), then: .Deferred/d.then(), 8 more… }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a callback instead that receives the response/data from your php:

```
$.post( "var_test.php", function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

That callback will be executed once the request has finished, that way, you can be sure that you will have your data ready and set to use it in your JS.

Comment: That helps quite a bit, but how do I get that variable outside of that function and into var thing?

Comment: Well, you are not supposed to use that variable outside the callback, why is this? because you are supposed to wait until the request has finished, otherwise you may end up getting undefined if you use it before time. You could define the var outside the callback, populate it inside the callback and use it wherever you want, but as I said, thats not recommendable because before the request has finished, the variable will have no value, thats the thing with AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

The `$.post()` isn't supposed to return your data, if you look closer at the 'big' object it has connection data.

You want this

```
$.post('var_test.php', function(myData) {
    console.log(myData);
});
```

Also you should be using `$.get()` for this sort of things, in exactly the same way

```
$.get('var_test.php', function(myData) {
    console.log(myData);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the jquery code, to request the content of a page you use the following code:

```
$.post( "var_test.php", function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
});
```

In the code you wrote $.post( "var_test.php") returns a jqXHR Object, it is an asynchronous call, so you need to use a callback, a more info can be found here:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/